# wpf: Inserting into related rows using DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I want to create a Window that lets me insert a Company with as many contactpersons I want. The relation between the tables I look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRDFC.jpg

This is the XAML for my window (the Grid and some other unnecessary details are omitted):

```
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3 3 3 3">Firmenname</Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="UiCompanyNameTextBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3 3 3 3" Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="3 3 3 3">Branche</Label>
    <ComboBox x:Name="UiBranchComboBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Margin="3 3 3 3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="BranchName" 
              SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Branch}"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="UiContactPersonDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
              Margin="3 3 3 3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Company}" Visibility="Collapsed"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="UiPersonDataGridComboBoxColumn" Header="Kontaktperson" DisplayMemberPath="Forename" 
                                    SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Person}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="UiPositionDataGridComboBoxColumn" Header="Position" DisplayMemberPath="Position" 
                                    SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Position}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is my code behind:

```
    public partial class AddCompany : Window
        {
            private DataRowView companyDataRowView;
            private ClientManager.ClientManagerDataSet.ContactPersonDataTable contactPersonDataTable;
```

`public AddCompany()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UiBranchComboBox.ItemsSource = DataSetManager.BranchTA.GetData();

            ClientManagerDataSet.CompanyDataTable companyDataTable = DataSetManager.CompanyTA.GetData();
            companyDataRowView = companyDataTable.DefaultView.AddNew();
            UiGrid.DataContext = companyDataRowView;
            companyDataRowView.BeginEdit();

            contactPersonDataTable = new ClientManager.ClientManagerDataSet.ContactPersonDataTable();
            DataView dv = contactPersonDataTable.DefaultView;
            UiContactPersonDataGrid.DataContext = contactPersonDataTable;

            UiPersonDataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = DataSetManager.PersonTA.GetData();
            UiPositionDataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = DataSetManager.PositionTA.GetData();
        }

        private void UiApplyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            companyDataRowView.EndEdit();
            DataSetManager.CompanyTA.Update(companyDataRowView.Row);
            DataSetManager.ContactPersonTA.Update(contactPersonDataTable);
            this.Close();
        }
    }`

The insertion of the company works. However, I am not able to bind the Datagrid so that it inserts the rows with the Company-Id of the new Company. 
Normally I would do this with a transaction, but since a DataSet is used I figured this must be possible somehow?

Comment: Check for xaml binding errors in debuggers output window while loading, and tell us what you see.

Comment: I dont see any errors occur, just many Loaded messages.